# RF device best way for capsulation (potting in a case)

Tags: potting

I need to encapsulate a Bluetooth beacon in the case, has to be flexible and weather resistant.

what would be your suggestion?

Comment: There’s generally three choices: silicones, polyurethanes and epoxies.  As to flexibility, you would need to determine the ‘hardness’ which is referred to as the Shore scale.  You’d also need to consider temperature range, cost, expected environment etc. There’s also the choice of fillers like silica crystals etc. Dow chemical (whatever there name is now!) have a range of specialty encapsulants so it would be worth seeking out their website to determine what chemistry is best suited to your application. Board assemblers should also be able to suggest something.

Comment: how can we prevent the potting compound goes around the antenna ?(it's a chip antenna)

Comment: You need to somehow protect your chip antenna from the elements otherwise it will corrode.  How to stop the goo touching the chip antenna? That’s a mechanical question. You need something to cover the antenna and the goo to seal it all up.